# How would I create a planet with exaggerated aurora?

Tags: planets

I want to create an earth-like planet with massive aurora, visible during the day, and from the equator. How would I go about doing this? Do I increase the strength of the planet's electromagnetic field, increase the amount of stellar wind, or both? If these are the solution, how do I create a stronger field, or increase the amount of wind?

Answer (score 5):

Here's the basics:

> When the charged particles from the sun strike atoms and molecules in Earth’s atmosphere, they excite those atoms, causing them to light up.
>
> What does it mean for an atom to be excited? Atoms consist of a central nucleus and a surrounding cloud of electrons encircling the nucleus in an orbit. When charged particles from the sun strike atoms in Earth’s atmosphere, electrons move to higher-energy orbits, further away from the nucleus. Then when an electron moves back to a lower-energy orbit, it releases a particle of light or photon. ([Source](http://earthsky.org/earth/what-causes-the-aurora-borealis-or-northern-lights))

Now, everything comes with a cost.  There isn't a way to get more lights without a consequence.  In reality, those lights represent something kinda bad: energy we don't want getting into the atmosphere.  So:

The magnetosphere channels the charged particles.  A stronger field means the northern lights are pushed even further north (because it channels the particles to the axis of the field).  So...

1. A weaker magnetic field will bring the lights further south and strengthen the lights further north, at the cost of exposing the north (and south) poles to greater radiation.

The atmosphere is receiving the charged particles and becoming excited to a higher energy state.  When they release the energy and fall back to a lower energy state, that release comes in the form of a *photon.*  Thus, more atmosphere at higher altitudes will produce more auroras.

2. Thicken the atmosphere.  Earth has something like 90% of its atmosphere in the first 10Km, the remaining 10% is between 10Km and 300Km.  Let's lower the gravity just a bit, increase the foilage a lot, increase neon an the other fluorescing atoms a bit, and we'll get more light higher up.  However, this will increase air pressure at sea level and decrease the value of the air to breathability.  The world becomes a bit uncomfortable to live on.

Now, for this last bit, I'm going to defer to our astrophysicist experts and give you just a summary.  The solar wind is made up of a lot of stuff, and not all of it will cause aurora.  We specifically want the *negatively* charged stuff.  So it's not really more volume we need ("more solar wind"), but a higher density of what makes life really cool near the poles.  And here's where I'm going to get this whole thing wrong (if I haven't already): I believe what we want is a cooler, larger, bluer sun.  (If I got that wrong, PLEASE correct me in comments!)

3. We want a sun that produces more of the charged particles that cause aurora.  However, this will affect the nature of life on your world.

Answer (score 2):

During the [Carrington event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_storm_of_1859) in 1859 auroras were brighter and visible way closer to the Equator than they normally do.

> Auroras were seen around the world, those in the northern hemisphere as far south as the Caribbean; those over the Rocky Mountains in the U.S. were so bright that the glow woke gold miners, who began preparing breakfast because they thought it was morning. People in the northeastern United States could read a newspaper by the aurora's light. The aurora was visible as far from the poles as south-central Mexico, Queensland, Cuba, Hawaii, southern Japan and China, and even at lower latitudes very close to the equator, such as in Colombia.

So, based on the above I would say that a more active star would help you in achieving your goal. Whether that will also be life friendly or not is another topic.